# Not able to call webApi from controller using jQuery Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

There are many questions related to webApi not getting called but i tried every solution and i am not able to get the right solution for my problem.
i have a webApi like this

```
public class shoppingCart : ApiController
{
   [HttpPost]
    public string getDetails()
    {
        return "HttpPost";
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public string getDetails1()
    {
        return "HttpGet";
    }
    [HttpPut]
    public string getDetails2()
    {
        return "HttpPut";

    }
    [HttpDelete]
    public string getDetails3()
    {
        return "HttpDelete";
    }
}
```

my global.asax.cs file is like this

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
}
```

my WebApiConfig.cs file is like this

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );    
    }
}
```

my routeConfig.cs file is like this

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

my jQuery Ajax script is like this

```
$('#btnAjax').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/shoppingCart/getDetails',
            success: function (returnData) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
```

whenever i try to call the web api i get an error

[image]

please somebody help me to fix the issue.
Thank you

Comment: @CodeCaster there is no need to mark my question with negative marks mate. i have searched for all the answers and the tiltle of the link which you provided was indeed no search friendly and thats why i was not able to read the answer which has been suggested in your given link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming your controller to `shoppingCartController`. As far as I know ASP.NET will look at the request and then search for a controller with the name request + `Controller`. I always try to be on the safe side by adding Controller.

Comment: thank you, changing the name to shoppingCartController solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("/api/shoppingCart/getDetails")]
 public string getDetails()
 {
    return "HttpPost";
 }
```

As stated in the comment, you should also add following line inside `WebApiConfig`

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
 {
           //this line
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    ....
 }
```

**Edit:**

As some other answers stated, you should also follow naming convention for your controllers, such as `ShoppingCartController`

Comment: You need to also mention how he should enable attribute routing. currently OP's WebApiConfig does not allow attribute routing

Comment: @Nkosi, I've updated my reply.

Comment: Introducing attribute routing for something that can just be done using regular routing is adding unnecessary (maintenance) overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You are not following naming convention for your controller

rename your controller

```
public class ShoppingCartController : ApiController { ... }
```